# Grant alter table on an entire schema to a group in redshift

Tags: sql, permissions, amazon-redshift, database-administration

I think I'm missing something when it comes to grant alter table. I'm looking at the AWS docs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html

And they say I can grant alter table to a role. I've tried running `grant alter table to user` but that gives me `SQL Error [0LP01]: ERROR: Grant/Revoke system privilege on User is not supported.`. So, I'm confused on what exactly a role in redshift is and how it works. Using rows, could I grant a group of people alter table permissions on a single schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant "ALTER TABLE" in this way.

```
create role testingaltertablerole;
create user testingaltertableuser with password disable;

grant alter table to role testingaltertablerole;

grant role testingaltertablerole to testingaltertableuser;
```

At the moment, there's no way to grant this permission for a single table, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are being crossed up by the fact the GRANT ALTER is for external datalake objects only.  It has to do with modifying the external datastore and isn't meant for normal Redshift tables.

If memory serves the ability to ALTER a normal table is linked with DROP permission.  Otherwise it is linked to table ownership.