# How can I grant alter table permission to a user for specific schemas in AWS Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, alter-table

I'm trying to make a user able to have alter table permission to all tables in a certain schema but not in other schemas in AWS Reshift.

So far, following the guidance here [Grant alter table on an entire schema to a group in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747105/grant-alter-table-on-an-entire-schema-to-a-group-in-redshift/74622865#74622865), I am table to do alter table to all tables in all schemas.

```
create role testingaltertablerole;
create user testingaltertableuser with password disable;

grant alter table to role testingaltertablerole;

grant role testingaltertablerole to testingaltertableuser;
```

How to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `ON SCHEMA xxx` work? `grant alter table on schema xxx to role testingaltertablerole;`

Comment: thanks for replaying, unfortunately it doesn't work